# CTreeCtrl TVITEM structure - text length

Tags: c++, mfc, ctree

I am not able to find (in MSDN), if parameter `int cchTextMax` of TVITEM structure is included the end null terminated string character `\0` or no.

`TVITEM` structure is used by CTreeCtrl or CTreeView class.

I mean, is it right
`cchTextMax = wcslen(lsTxt)`
or
`cchTextMax = wcslen(lsTxt)+1`
??

Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 3):

Per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/ns-commctrl-tvitema):

`cchTextMax`

Type: **int**

***Size of the buffer** pointed to by the pszText member, in characters. If this structure is being used to **set** item attributes, this member is **ignored**.*

So, you don't use `cchTextMax` to set the text of an item.

But to retrieve the text you need a buffer to receive it, and `cchTextMax` is the buffer size, so this includes the terminating null. For example:

```
TVITEM tvi;
TCHAR sBuff[BUF_MAX];

.
.
tvi.pszText = sBuff;
tvi.cchTextMax = BUF_MAX;  // Or:
tvi.cchTextMax = sizeof(sBuff)/sizeof(TCHAR);
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you insert callback items you don't insert text, instead you set `pszText` to `LPSTR_TEXTCALLBACK`, and you must process the `TVN_GETDISPINFO` notification, ie the system is asking you "what text should I display for this item?". You can just set `pszText` to point to a buffer or copy your data to the buffer already pointed by `pszText` - you may copy up to `cchTextMax` TCHARs in the latter case.

Comment: I use callback, SetDispInfo and GetDispInfo. It means, I must have buffer size to include biggest text, what user can input when edit cell (item)?   And if I have read-only item, I could cchTextMax dismiss?    ....And if I fill the item on ctrl init, without callback, I could also omit cchTextMax?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the TreeView documentation does not say explicitly whether or not `cchTextMax` includes the null terminator (on the other hand, the ListView documentation does say, and ListView and TreeView are implemented in the same library, so it is likely that they behave similarly).

Since `pszText` points to a **null-terminated string**, and `cchTextMax` is the **size** of the `pszText` buffer in characters, it stands to reason that `cchTextMax` includes the null terminator.  Particularly when retrieving text, since `TVM_GETITEM` and similar messages need to know how large the buffer is so they can store the null terminator and truncate text if needed.